# Maxwell, speed of light and the electric permittivity and magnetic constants

Tags: electromagnetism, speed-of-light, history, aether

1. When Maxwell found that the already-measured speed of light could also be derived from the already-measured electric and magnetic constants, what were the electric and magnetic constants measured to be at that time?
2. Were their values related with the ether?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.4719v2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The constant of magnetic permeability = $1.2566370614… \times 10^{−6} H \times m^{−1}$

The electric constant  ≈ $8.854187817620... \times 10^{−12}$

These constants have to do with the resistance of an electric or magnetic field permeating through a classical vacuum.